# ios get the headers from NSURLRequest I get error [NSConcreteMutableData allHeaderFields]: unrecognized selector

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlrequest, nshttpurlresponse

I'm trying to get the headers of the NSURLRequest with the following line:

```
NSString *contentType = [[(NSHTTPURLResponse *)data allHeaderFields] valueForKey:@"Content-Type"];
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
-[NSConcreteMutableData allHeaderFields]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d876e0
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteMutableData allHeaderFields]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d876e0'
```

Any of guys know why of this error or how can I fixed or what I'm doing wrong?

I'll really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is a `NSData` instance, not a `NSHTTURLResponse` as you think.

That's why it doesn't recognize the selector `allHeaderFields` that you're sending to it.

Comment: got it. I was calling in the wrong place:- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)detailConnection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    self.responseData = [NSMutableData data];
    NSString *contentType = [[(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response allHeaderFields] valueForKey:@"Content-Type"];